# Close Modal From Child Component in Angular 6

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal

I was trying to close a modal from my child component but I am not able to close it.

Could anybody suggest me the idea here.

I am using @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap

below is my code:
parent.html

```
<ng-template #templateref let-modal>
  <childcomp  [modalRef]="modalRef" (return)='onReturn($event)'>

  </childcomp>
</ng-template>
```

Child.component.ts

```
@Input modalref:NgbModalRef;
onclose(){
this.modalref.close();
}
```

child.html

```
<div class="modal-header"></div><div class="modal-body"></div>
```

I am getting close() not a function as error.

Comment: You have used @Output decoration which is wrong. It used for event not for data.

Comment: by mistake i wrote output instead of input

Comment: Can you geneate the demo ?

Comment: its a angular code will take too much time to generate demo, apart from it i have mentioned the code snippet which is similar scenario